# C# Timer - Need help disabling timer until code executes then restart timer. Currently maxing CPU :(

Tags: c#, timer, cpu

Basically i have a problem with this timer program I am trying to put together. On starting the program it will utilise a steady 25% CPU which i dont mind, but every time the timer fires it adds another 25% on to the CPU so on the 4th pass im completely maxed out.

I take it I'm not disposing of the timer correctly after it has fired but im new to c# and not really sure how to go about this.

the cope of my program is basically:

- Execute some procedures - once completed start timer
- Wait until timer elapses then start procedures again, disabling the timer until completed

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    IpCheck();
}

private static void EnableTimer()
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    // Set the Interval to x seconds.
    aTimer.Interval = 10000;
    aTimer.Enabled=true;
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
    aTimer.Dispose();
}
```

ok revised version below - simplified and ruled out the ip check so all it does now is show a message box - this will not even execute anymore :(

```
public class Timer1        
{

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public static void Main()
    {

        Timer1 tTimer = new Timer1();
        tTimer.EnableTimer();

       }


    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        MessageBoxPrint();
        aTimer.Enabled = true;


    }
    private void EnableTimer()
    {

        // Set the Interval to x seconds.
        aTimer.Interval = 10000;
        aTimer.Enabled=true;
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);


    }


    public static void MessageBoxPrint()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Testing");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're problem is not shown in the code posted. You almost certainly have an infinite loop inside `IpCheck()`. Let me guess, you're on a 4-core machine, which is why you're seeing each pass add 25% to the CPU - each pass is consuming an entire core at 100%. However, this suggests you are starting new threads, which you haven't shown in this code either.

Comment: simplified things as shown above to only output a message box and still hvaing the same issue with CPU :(

Comment: tTimer is a Timer1, which creates another tTimer, which creates another tTimer etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

// This method will be called at the interval specified in EnableTimer
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Enabled = false;  // stop timer
    IpCheck();
    aTimer.Enabled = true;   // restart timer so this method will be called in X secs
}

private static void EnableTimer()
{
    // Set the Interval to x seconds.
    aTimer.Interval = 10000;
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    aTimer.Enabled=true;  // actually starts timer
}
```

Comment: aTimer needs to be a class level member, atm its local to the EnableTimer method

Comment: thanks this seems to have eventually done the trick for me, the cpu issue was the recreation of the timer object so i restructured everything a bit and its now working perfectly - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't quit get, why you have the cpu load, but I would do:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Timer)source).Enabled = false;
    IpCheck();
    ((Timer)source).Enabled = true;
}
```

and don't dispose the timer in the method call.

Comment: getting the message "'Object' does not contain a definition for 'Enabled' and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found..."  but this seems to be in line with how i'd like to approach it - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
static System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

aTimer.Enabled=false;

            IpCheck();

aTimer.Enabled=true;
        }

        private static void EnableTimer()
        {
            // Set the Interval to x seconds.
            aTimer.Interval = 10000;
            aTimer.Enabled=true;
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        }
private static void DisableTimer()
{


aTimer.Elapsed -= new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Enabled = false;


}
```

NOT TESTED NOT COMPILED, just a sample what i would do in your place, all the added lines are there without no tabs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that he is creating a Timer1 inside the Timer1 class  so when you load Timer1, it loads another Timer1 which loads another timer1 which loads....  It think you get it

```
public class Timer1        
{

System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
public static void Main()
{

    Timer1 tTimer = new Timer1();//<-this line right here is killing you 
                                 //remove it, as I don't see anyuse for it at all
```

then in this line

```
 tTimer.EnableTimer();
```

just say

```
EnableTimer();
//or
this.EnableTimer();
```

You don't need to instantiate the class you are working in, as far as it is concerned it is already instantiated.